# Old Sata / Sas Controller on Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, sata

I have recently bought a new motherboard (ASUS ROG Strix B650E-F GAMING WIFI + AMD Ryzen 9 7900 CPU) and moved over an old SATA controller from an old rig (Iocrest si-pex40097). It will work no problem under Windows 11 without any extra drivers / software.

However, I am wanting to setup linux (Ubuntu Server) so i can setup RAID on multiple drives. Having tried Linux 22.04.2 the drives cant be seen.

This Sata controller did work in my old rig using ubuntu server 18 without additional drivers.

I have tried using the instructions found here (https://www.sybausa.com/index.php?route=product/product/download&download_id=225) but they seem to be for older version of grub.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Dave

Comment: It may be that you need a newer controller, there being no drivers for the older one

Comment: Hi John, I am already leaning that way but out of hope to save some money ;).

Comment: Editing the question to include the output of ``lspci -nn`` to identify the controller PCI identity could help. From a search think the ``si-pex40097`` uses the Marvell 88SE9215 chipset. https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:1b4b-9215-1b4b-9215&page=8#status suggests the 88SE9215 has been detected in Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score -1):

#### Finding the expected PCI vendor and device ID for the SATA controller

The question says the SATA controller card is an `Iocrest si-pex40097`.

The product page [16 Port SATA PCI-e 2.0 x4 Card - SI-PEX40097](https://www.sybausa.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=722) says:

> Chipset: Marvell 9215

The PCI ID Repository has [Name: 88SE9215 PCIe 2.0 x1 4-port SATA 6 Gb/s Controller](https://admin.pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/1b4b/9215) with the identity:

> Vendor 1b4b
>
> Device 9215

#### Unable to find an in-box Kernel module in Ubuntu 22.04 or 18.04 which supports the Marvell 9215

With a `Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS` installation and a `5.15.0-100-generic` Kernel used the following to scan the modules to see which supported the Marvell vendor id of `1B4B`:

```
find /lib/modules/5.15.0-100-generic/ -name '*.ko' | xargs -n 1 modinfo | grep 1B4B
```

The above didn't find any in-box modules which support `pci:v00001B4Bd00009215` which is for the Marvell 9215 chipset.

In the Linux kernel source code `PCI_VENDOR_ID_MARVELL_EXT` is the identifier for the Marvell vendor id of `0x1b4b`.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.100/C/ident/PCI_VENDOR_ID_MARVELL_EXT is the references to the `PCI_VENDOR_ID_MARVELL_EXT` identifier in the Kernel version in use with the Ubuntu 22.04 installation. Looking at the references:

1. [drivers/ata/ahci.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.100/source/drivers/ata/ahci.c#L556) : No entry for the `0x9215` identity, but for other Marvell identities. This is the source code for the `ahci.ko` module which is the *AHCI SATA low-level driver*. I.e. the lack of the `0x9215` identity means the in-box `ahci.ko` module doesn't support the Marvell 9215 chipset.
2. [drivers/pci/quirks.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.100/source/drivers/pci/quirks.c#L4144) does reference the `0x9215` identity:

   ```
    /* https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42679#c135 */
    DECLARE_PCI_FIXUP_HEADER(PCI_VENDOR_ID_MARVELL_EXT, 0x9215,
                 quirk_dma_func1_alias);
   ```

   Which is applying a fix for a quirk in the Marvell 9215 chipset
3. [drivers/scsi/mvsas/mv_init.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.100/source/drivers/scsi/mvsas/mv_init.c#L658) : No entry for the `0x9215` identity
4. [drivers/scsi/mvumi.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.100/source/drivers/scsi/mvumi.c#L37) : No entry for the `0x9215` identity

Also booted a `Ubuntu 18.04.1` live DVD, and with the older Ubuntu distribution also didn't find any in-box Kernel module which supported the Marvell 9215 chipset.

I.e. does't appear that in-box support for the Marvell 9215 chipset was removed between Ubuntu 18.04 and 22.04, in that support isn't in either.

#### How to set all_generic_ide with GRUB 2

From the question:

> I have tried using the instructions found here (https://www.sybausa.com/index.php?route=product/product/download&download_id=225) but they seem to be for older version of grub.

The above linked instruction say to modify `menu.lst`:

> 3. Type the following commands:
>
>    ```
>    ls
>    cd/boot/grub
>    vim menu.lst
>    ```
> 4. Type the following command at the end of the kernel line for the title
>    paragraph that lists the version information for the Linux distribution.
>
>    ```
>    ata_generic.all_generic_ide=1
>    ```

Ubuntu 22.04 uses GRUB 2.06, in which the `menu.lst` configuration file has been replaced with `/etc/default/grub`. See [Configuring GRUB 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2) for the Ubuntu instructions on how to configure GRUB 2.

Suggest try the following in Ubuntu 22.04 to try and get the `Iocrest si-pex40097` SATA controller to work:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `ata_generic.all_generic_ide=1` into the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. E.g.:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ata_generic.all_generic_ide=1"
   ```
2. After making changes and saving the file, the GRUB 2 menu must be updated to include the changes by running:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Reboot

With Ubuntu 22.04.04.LTS checked that the `ata_generic` module does contain the `all_generic_ide` parameter:

```
$ modinfo ata_generic
name:           ata_generic
filename:       (builtin)
version:        0.2.15
license:        GPL
file:           drivers/ata/ata_generic
description:    low-level driver for generic ATA
author:         Alan Cox
parm:           all_generic_ide:int
```

**Note**: I don't have the hardware to confirm the above instructions will work.

Comment: Hi Chester, Thanks for taking the time to look, unfortunately this has not worked either. I have also tried connecting the OS drive to the controller, it will start the boot process, so I think the motherboard can see grub through the controller but not the remainder of the drive.

Comment: So I'm currently thinking that as a stop gap, I will use my old motherboard as a pure NAS. It has a i7-2xxx processor which should handle the linux RAID nicely as well as a webdav service and Samba.